# In linux, how can we change bash environment variables using initialize script?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, bashrc

We know that we can change bash's environment variables, for example `PATH`, using initialize script, for example `.bashrc`. Just writing `PATH=<VALUE>` and you will get what you want.

But, consider this problem:

We have a bash script named `rc`:

```
#!/bin/bash  

mySite="superUser"
export mySite
echo "the value of mySite is: $mySite"
```

Then we declare the variable `mySite`, execute the `rc` script, and then check the the variable's value:

```
$ declare -x mySite="super"
$ ./rc 
the value of mySite is: superUser
$ echo $mySite
super
```

The value is still `super`. can we conclude that child shell cannot change parent shell's variable directly using the instruction like `VARIALBENAME=VLAUE`?

Our `rc` script is just like `.bashrc`, and how can we change the bash's environment variable's value by placing the `PATH=<VLAUE>` in it, for when `.bashrc`'s execution is over, the variable of the calling shell is still not changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are *inherited* ... and parent processes don't inherit anything from their children (it works in the other direction).

In your first case, the bash process reading the rc file is either the same process in which you use the variable, or its ancestor.

In your second case, the process reading the file is the child of your shell. There are 3 ways around this:

1. have your script start a *new* shell, which inherits the variables. Your original shell will resume (with it's original environment) when you exit
2. *source* the rc script rather than executing it:

   ```
   . ./rc
   ```

   or

   ```
   source ./rc
   ```

   instructs your current shell to read the script itself (rather than executing it in a child) and then resume
3. explicitly evaluate the output (as is usually done with `ssh-agent` for example)

   ```
   eval `./rc`
   ```

   where rc has changed to

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "export mySite=\"superUser\""
   ```